# Нужна помощь с ботом в телеграме на python, не работают инлайн кнопки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня версия python 3.9
Использую библиотеки `telebot`, `os`, `platform`
Проблема в том что когда я в самом боте пишу команду `/panel` должно отправляться меню из инлайн кнопок и по нажатии на кнопку должна выполняться другая команда , но кнопки не реагируют на нажатия, мне нужна помощь . Помогите пожалуйста . Суть бота в том что по нажатии кнопки "Информация об ПК" бот должен присылать инфу об системе и железе, сама команда работает, а вот кнопка нет. При нажатии на кнопку бот присылает сообщение `/info` и больше ничего не происходит.

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types
import os
import platform

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['info']) # Данная команда выводит основную информацию о ПК
def start_message5(message5):
    machine0 = platform.machine()
    machine1 = platform.version()
    machine2 = platform.platform()
    machine3 = platform.processor()
    machine4 = socket.gethostname()
    bot.send_message(message5.chat.id, machine0)
    bot.send_message(message5.chat.id, machine1)
    bot.send_message(message5.chat.id, machine2)
    bot.send_message(message5.chat.id, machine3)
    bot.send_message(message5.chat.id, machine4)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['panel'])
def start_message10(message10):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Информация об ПК", callback_data="/info")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message10.chat.id, text="Выбери действие", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['/info'])
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == '/info':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, call.data) # Вот тут проблема, тут я так и не понял что нужно указать
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['/info'])
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == '/info':
        start_message5(call.message)
```

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь работает)